# MS Access: If/else condition to display data in a Form

Tags: ms-access

I have created a form that allows a user to select a Company and input an Amount.
e.g.
Company Name | Taxable
ABC | YES
BCD | YES
CDE | NO
DEF | NO
...... and the list goes on

Currently, the form will display 2 calculated amounts for each company (YES and NO), with and without tax. How and where do I insert a condition such that my Form only displays the Amount with tax for YES and Amount without tax for NO?

EDIT 1:
YES and NO values are stored as text.

My form is a based on a query that gets data from multiple tables. There is a Product table that actually calculates and stores both Taxed and Untaxed values using different formulas. The form will display these 2 fields as the Taxed and Untaxed values.

EDIT 2:

My SELECT statement for the query which joins the tables to create my form

Initial:
SELECT [Refund].[Request Date], [Refund].[Adj Date], [Refund].[Company ID], Company.[Company Name], Company.[Taxable], [Refund].[Product Name], [Product].Stake, [Product].[Sales Comm Amount], [Product].[GST on SC], [Product].[TaxedAmount], [Product].[UntaxedAmount]
FROM Company INNER JOIN ([Product] INNER JOIN [Refund] ON [Product].[Product Name] = [Refund].[Product Name]) ON Company.[Company ID] = [Refund].[Company ID];

Tried with new line:
SELECT [Refund].[Request Date], [Refund].[Adj Date], [Refund].[Company ID], Company.[Company Name], Company.[Taxable], [Refund].[Product Name], [Product].Stake, [Product].[Sales Comm Amount], [Product].[GST on SC], [Product].[TaxedAmount], [Product].[UntaxedAmount], IIF([Taxable]="YES", [TaxedAmount], [UntaxedAmount]) AS FinalAmount
FROM Company INNER JOIN ([Product] INNER JOIN [Refund] ON [Product].[Product Name] = [Refund].[Product Name]) ON Company.[Company ID] = [Refund].[Company ID];

Also created an empty column in my [Refund] table called FinalAmount hoping that the IIF function would store a value at the end. However, I was met with the message "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect." when trying to save in SQL view.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *ControlSource* like this for your textbox that displays the amount:

```
=IIf([Taxable],[AmountWithTax],[AmountWithoutTax])
```

If/when Taxable is stored as text (it really shouldn't):

```
=IIf([Taxable]="YES",[AmountWithTax],[AmountWithoutTax])
```

or, if the separator is localised:

```
=IIf([Taxable]="YES";[AmountWithTax];[AmountWithoutTax])
```

For use in a query:

```
Select *, IIf([Taxable]="YES",[AmountWithTax],[AmountWithoutTax]) As TaxedAmount
From YourTable
```

Comment: Hey Gustav, I'm sorry I wasn't really clear in my question. I have edited it. In my case, I have tried to create another empty text box using the Form's design view and input the formula you gave as follows: =IIf( [Refund Query]![Taxable] like \*YES\*, [Refund Query]![AmountWithTax] , [Refund Query]![AmountWithoutTax] ), it says "You may have entered a comma without a preceding value or identifier". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with your second line! Now that it displays the correct value, how do I have it stored in my table? Since my form is based on querying a few tables, the data will be stored in the query's Datasheet view. I need the displayed value in the textbox to be reflected as well so that users can export the file. Is that possible?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. That's what queries are for. See edited answer.

Comment: Do you mean I have to modify my query that pulls data from different tables in the first place? The form is based on a query wizard that "combines" 3 tables. Do you mean I have to add in this line along with those in my query wizard? I have no clue where to input the line for use in a query. So sorry! If I could send you a sample of my work it would be great.

Comment: Yes, open the query in SQL and modify the select statement. However, if you are not familiar with this, you should use the first approach using an unbound textbox having the _ControlSource_ as specified.

Comment: I have edited the post with my SELECT statement. I have tried adding your suggested query line at the end but it doesn't work (since I'm unclear of the required structure/syntax). What is the correct way to append the new line?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you have done. Again, using the _ControlSource_ method would be the easiest to implement.

Comment: I have already tried using the control source method you specified. The result is only displayed but not saved in the records thereafter.

Comment: That's right. You shouldn't save values that, at any time, can be easily calculated again either, as now, on the form or, as shown, using a query.